# UITableViewCell addSubview vs insertSubview:atIndex:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So my issue is that to my cell I want to add a view with a tap gesture recogniser on it. At first I added it using insertSubview:view atIndex:0, but in stead of the gesture recogniser firing the didSelectRow:atIndexPath was firing. After long troubleshooting I found that if I add it using addSubview it worked. Im guessing that the insertView:atIndex was inserting the view below the UITableViewCell.contentView and that's why the didSelectRow:atIndexPath was firing in stead of the gesture recogniser and I just want to know if that's true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: You're right.

By calling insertSubview:view atIndex:0, you're setting the z-value of view to be the lowest possible value. You're telling the superview that you want all other views within the superview to be overlaid on top of view.

Calling addSubview adds the new view on top of the stack of views present in the superview; thus giving it a maximal z-value.

You can use the number of subviews currently present in the superview if you'd still prefer to use the first method as follows:

```
[someSUperView insertSubview:view atIndex:([[view subviews] count] -1)];
```